# Does this question lack clarity?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, unclear, regex

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78066179) asks for something quite trivial: A way to negate the regex `^[A-Z]{4}$` in the context of a specific tool that only supports POSIX regexes. It was originally closed as a duplicate of the generic *[Regex: match everything but a specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687620)*.

I voted to reopen it since there is at least one valid answer that doesn't belong to the dupe target (which I posted as CW), and the closer agreed with me: it was reopened in a matter of hours.

However, when I saw the question again today, I found out that it was closed as "Needs details or clarity". How is this the case? I think it is both specific and clear and therefore should not be closed.

Comment: I edited the question a bit so it is more about Overpass API rather than just inverting a regex.

Comment: *"It was originally closed as a duplicate of the generic Regex: match everything but a specific pattern"*. A very common occurrence on the site. It all boils down to: do you like lists of things or not? I personally find that Stack Overflow sucks at managing them so we shouldn't do that. But the dupe link... it is a list of things in the making. There is an answer for Python, and an answer for PHP. There could have been an answer for Overpass API too and then the dupe link would have been... according to the rules. I personally support your choice to just go ahead and not do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question asks how to negate the regex. It's not clear whether that means "use the regex syntax to produce a regex that matches everything else", or "use a logical negation operator in the context surrounding the regex".

The former is clearly a duplicate. (There are other possible candidates: e.g. [How to negate the whole regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637675/))

The latter is probably trivial; but in case it isn't (and it [might not be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542732)), the question should be explicitly framed this way, and it also isn't really about the regex, but about the negation process in that surrounding context (i.e. the "overpass-turbo" tool).

(It's not entirely clear to me that the latter is a programming question, anyway - it seems like this tool is meant for use by the general public, it just happens to have a vaguely programmer-like interface. A question about how to use `AND` and `OR` in a search engine's query syntax probably wouldn't be on topic, either, unless it were a [language-agnostic question about logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/)....)

At any rate, it shouldn't be *both* questions. If that were acceptable (i.e, not judged as Needs More Focus), we'd already have a clear surrounding-language-agnostic canonical specifically meant to cover the concept of "or you could do it in the surrounding code".

Comment: Overpass-Turbo basically seems to be a UI on top of Overpass API, kind of equivalent to a SQL Editor tool. The Overpass API can obviously be used in a programming context so it can be considered a programming question, I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

No, but it is a duplicate of [Regex: match everything but a specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687620/5349916).

Said question already has [an answer for the generic approach of using a positive pattern but inverting the match in the host language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1687637/5349916). There is even a comment alluding to exactly the kind of operator that also applies in this case.

---

FWIW, in the spirit of [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) it may be suitable to extend the answer or post a new one that shows common operators. Regex operators seem to be a small set as are negation operators.